# Trying to create a war with the exist-db 5.3.0 release

Tags: xml, database, web, war, exist-db

The last release downloable in war format was the 4.7.1. I've been trying to turn the 5.3.0 release into a war since the project i'm working in needs it that way and i want to upgrade the exist version. Hopefully someone out there is working on something similar or has already achieved this modification succesfully and could help me a little. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked on the [exist-open](https://sourceforge.net/projects/exist/lists/exist-open) mailing list. Quoting from [the thread](https://markmail.org/message/6g5ipdolli7ufkej):

Question:

> Is it still possible at all to craft WAR build for eXist-5 (perhaps in an unofficial community-driven effort), or is that technically just impossible?

Answer:

> Yes it is possible using Maven and some plugins. You could add an additioal
> module to eXist-db's Multi-module Maven build which has a war
> . Given a couple days I or someone familiar with Maven and
> eXist-db could probably figure it out. However, I really don't want to do
> that (at least as part of the project) as we are for "sensible reasons"
> trying to avoid running multiple eXist-db inside a Servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

The general consensus is that running eXist/a database in a tomcat container is a bad idea. At least the core team does not want to support this route as there are many issues with class loaders, location of writing data etc. The testing/support costs too much effort.

We do recommend to run eXist-db in a docker container, this is well tested, very stable and a industry standard. We provide secure containers to the community.